# Chat application in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, dhtml

Which technologies I need to learn for developing Online Chat Room with voice/video support?
Presently I know Core PHP/MySql and DHTML.

Comment: You need to learn the audio and video technology as well as the transfer data over internet technology in the language of your choice.  However if you choose a language that is not capable of that (PHP, mysql, HTML and DHTML can not do what you're looking for), you have choosen the wrong language. Maybe you need to look into C and/or Java.

Comment: PHP with Flash (Action Script) wouldn't solve the purpose?

Comment: Probably flash alone would solve it. However I'm not really sure if Action Script supports real time video streaming and syncing between multiple partners.

Comment: @hakre Adobe Media Server (http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), and before that Flash Communication Server, has been supporting real-time streaming and audio/video chat using ActionScript for well over a decade now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a chat that would scale, you need to learn how to write an event handled application, there is a lot of framework to build such application, a short list

- [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
- [python twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)
- etc...

This tool would permit you to use the [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) style of ajax call.

Sadly, I don't think there is any event driven web server/framework for PHP, so you would probably have to learn other language.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets do suit the job best. That means you ought to study some javascript and a serverside technology of your choice. http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Comment: You have any information about how to pass realtime video data over websockets?

Comment: Websockets do allow a stream of data, thus it is rather question how to render it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free API called TokBox that I've used for custom video chat applications in the past:

http://www.tokbox.com/

You'll have to build a back end for storing and passing chat sessions, but it has a very robust javascript library that lets you control the number of participants, the position and size of screens, audio controls, etc etc etc... and it has developer libraries in php and several other languages that help you connect to their servers to back-end controls (including downloading and archiving chats).

It's well documented, and I was able to get a fairly customized system up in about a day.